# Codeigniter - can’t upload image through input type file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating recipe book in PHP Codeigniter. I have a problem with uploading image to resource folder and save image path to dtb. All the data successfully save to database except file (image).
View.

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('Recipes/add'); ?>
       <table style="padding: 15px;">
    <tr>
        <td><label for="title">Title:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" id="title" name="title"  required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="category">Category:</label></td>
        <td>
            <select id="category" name="category">
                <?php 
                    foreach($categories as $row1){
                        print "<option value=" . $row1->id . ">";
                        print $row1->title;
                        print "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="ingredients">Ingredients:</label></td>
        <td><textarea name="ingredients" id="ingredients" required></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <label for="production_method">Production method:</label></td>
           <td><textarea name="production_method" id="production_method" required></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <label for="production_time">Production time:</label></td>
          <td><input type="production_time" name="production_time" id="production_time"  required/> minutes</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
       <td> <label for="image_path">Upload an image:</label></td>
          <td><input type="file"name="image_path"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  <input type="submit" value="Save recipe" id="submit" name="submit"/></td>
        <td> <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller

```
class Recipes extends CI_Controller{
     public function __construct(){     
        //call CodeIgniter's default Constructor
                parent::__construct();

                //load database libray manually
                $this->load->database();

                //load Model
                $this->load->model('Recipe_model');

                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

                //load registration view form
                $this->load->model("Category_model");

            }                     
            public function add(){
                $data['categories']= $this->Category_model->get_categories();
                //call a function of the loaded view
                $this->load->view("templates/header");
                //we load a view to display the results
                $this->load->view("new_insert",$data);
                $this->load->view("templates/footer");

                    $config['upload_path'] = "/CI/assets/imgs/";
                    $config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg";
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


                //Check submit button 
                if($this->input->post('submit')){
                    // if ($this->upload->do_upload('image_path')){
                    //get form's data and store in local varable
                    $title=$this->input->post('title');
                    $category=$this->input->post('category');
                    $ingredients=$this->input->post('ingredients');
                    //$image_path=$this->input->post('image_path');
                    $this->upload->do_upload('image_path'); 
                    $image_path= $this->upload->data();
                    $production_method=$this->input->post('production_method');
                    $production_time=$this->input->post('production_time');

                    $this->Recipe_model->form_insert([
                        'title' => $title,
                        'category_id' => $category,
                        'ingredients' => $ingredients,
                        'production_method' => $production_method,
                        'production_time' => $production_time,
                        'image_path' => $image_path['image_path']
                    ]);
                    redirect("Recipes/dispdata"); 
                }
            }
```

I tried to use Codeigniter documentation, but couldn’t work. I will be very greatful for every response, I am new in MVC. Thank you.

Comment: You don't check for return values on any of your function calls. How will you even know where the error is? Figure that out is step one, then worry about how to fix it.

Comment: if you looked at the docs you would see `$this->upload->do_upload('image_path');` should be wrapped in an if with `$this->upload->display_errors();` inside. this way you can see *why* it is failing; probably the image is too big or the file type is wrong. also consider using form validation.

Comment: Thank you for response. Now i got an error: The upload path does not appear to be valid. When i replaced image_path by full_path, than i got only path of folder, where should be images saved. BTW: I use an image to homepage from this folder and it works.

Comment: i'm not sure of your folder structure but `/CI/assets/imgs/` has to be a valid folder. also it should probably be `./CI/assets/imgs/`